LT spice transformer generates DC offset (down)
I have a half bridge driver that generates a square wave that goes into a transformer to step it up from 12v to 325v.
The problem is that once I connect the square wave to the transformer the voltage shift down, so instead of having a square wave of 0v-12 I get a square wave of 1.4v - negative 5.8v.
when the transformer is disconnected it goes back to normal (even if under load).
Anybody knows what is the problem? 

You've annotated that section as "full bridge", but it's only a half bridge.


Anybody knows what is the problem?

The primary winding is an inductor and this will force the primary voltage to have an average value of zero volts.
This happens due to the inductor formula: \$V = L\frac{di}{dt}\$. When the upper transistor (M3) activates, primary current ramps up at a rate of V/L amps per second. When the lower transistor (M4) activates, 0 volts is applied across the transformer hence, current remains at what it was when the upper transistor was deactivated.
When the upper transistor reactivates, it starts ramping up current at a rate of V/L but, it does so from the amperage value it currently has. This means you get a ramping staircase of current that never ends theoretically. Within a few milli or microseconds you get complete core saturation and usually one of the transistors or the inductor fails. This then forces (or allows) the average voltage across an inductor to be zero volts.
If you want to drive a transformer this way you must use a series capacitor. Or, use a H-bridge drive. You have to block any DC voltages.

The default DCR of an LTspice inductor is 0.001 ohm, which implies an average current of ~4kA in your inductor.
As Andy says, use a capacitor coupling and if you do use an H-bridge without a capacitor make sure there is enough resistance in the circuit to keep the core from saturating due to any slight asymmetry.

WOW thank you guys. Forgot all about core saturation.
